# Is it safe to point to 32 bits of a 64 bit number?

Tags: c++

I am using xorshift* to generate random 64 bit numbers and want to use the most significant 32 bits as my output. Is there anything unsafe about just creating a pointer to the most significant bits and returning that value? I know that I could just use a bitshift, but I am hoping to compare that option to this one for performance. I have done basic testing on this method and it seems to work as expected under all g++ optimization levels but I am unsure if it is defined behavior, and if not that it may cause problems as the project develops.

```
uint64_t  seed = 0x2cf915021e8312a0;            // randomly chosen from random.org
uint32_t* seed_msb = (uint32_t*)(&seed) + 1;    // +1 to account for endianness

uint32_t xorshiftStar32(){
    seed ^= seed >> 12;
    seed ^= seed << 25;
    seed ^= seed >> 27;
    return (*seed_msb) * (uint64_t)(0x2545f4914f6cdd1d);
}
```

The testing I have done so far is just checking that each time xorshiftStar32() is called, the seed updates and the function returns the updated result.

Comment: I believe Endianness is going to be a problem, if you are going to write portable code

Comment: yes it should be safe.

Comment: FYI: [What is the Strict Aliasing Rule and Why do we care?](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8). The `// +1 to account for endianness` scared me a bit. I assume you want to move the 32 bit pointer to the "middle" of the 64 bit value to handle endianess issues? May be, a `uint8_t[8]` would be the better choice. (The compiler is a bit more tolerant for `char*` including the `unsigned char*` variant.)

Comment: This breaks the strict aliasing rule, and `(uint32_t*)(&seed) + 1` also has undefined behaviour. If you want to select bits, shift them. It's both portable and safe

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about that. Will definitely have to give it a read. I am not really concerned about the portability aspect since that could be done with guess-and-check. My main concern is the compiler optimizing something away or switching order without accounting for the output depending on the seed.

Comment: Can you clarify what the intended behaviour is on a big-endian system? Not sure if you want the mathematically upper 32 bits,  or whether you want the last 32 in memory

Comment: I want the 32 most significant bits (mathematically). The code is currently only intended for my particular laptop, so this seems to work. I would remove the +1 for a big-endian system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, but a little on the dodgy side *(given that you are modifying seed within your function, it's going to be a register value, so accessing through a pointer is not going to be as efficient)*. In this case, you'd be better off just using bitshift to extract the 32bits.

```cpp
uint64_t seed = 0x2cf915021e8312a0;            // randomly chosen from random.org

uint32_t xorshiftStar32() {
    seed ^= seed >> 12;
    seed ^= seed << 25;
    seed ^= seed >> 27;
    return (seed >> 32) * (uint64_t)(0x2545f4914f6cdd1d);
}
```

Which actually results in marginally better asm *(note we've switched a mov, for a shift)* https://godbolt.org/z/-49tZE

Comment: Not to forget that your variant is endianess-agnostic... ;-)

Comment: The lack of multiplication is on me, I added it as an edit. Thanks for the link! I will definitely be referencing this site as I move forward, learning a bit of asm on the way hopefully.

Comment: The reason that the assembly output is "marginally better" (if, in fact, it even is) would be because you've substituted a memory-accessing instruction for one that does not access memory. It has nothing to do with the fact that it's a `MOV`. In general, register moves are *way* faster than shifts.

Answer (score 4):

No, this causes undefined behaviour. According to the strict aliasing rule, you can only read from a `uint32_t` lvalue if it refers to a `uint32_t` object  (or a similar object as covered by the rule).

A simple fix is to use `memcpy` to transfer the bytes you want into a `uint32_t` variable , or use bitmask/shift/etc. to extract the part.

Comment: using memcpy here would still result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Which 4 bytes can you safely copy from the 64bit seed variable above? In a way that is agnostic of LSB/MSB, and doesn't break strict aliasing rules?

Comment: @robthebloke `memcpy` never breaks strict aliasing, you can copy any 4 bytes you like into a `uint32_t` variable